# NetLogo: how to use tick in correct context

Tags: netlogo

I am relatively new to NetLogo and have been trying to figure this out for quite some time.  I have a search path algorithm that determines the optimal path for each turtle (ship) in my model, storing each path as a separate list of patches. The goal is to have the turtles traverse along the list of patches while having the tick counter increase each step the turtles take (i.e. a tick every time all the turtles move from one patch to the next) - until it reaches the destination. Seems pretty simple but for some reason I can't seem to figure out the correct way to use the context of 'tick'.

Here's an example of my code corresponding to the movement portion (once the lists of paths have already been generated).

```
to move
  tick
  ask-concurrent ships
    [
      while [length current-path != 0]
      [ 
        face first current-path
        move-to first current-path
        set current-path remove-item 0 current-path
        wait 0.08
      ]
    ]

end
```

Currently the tick counter only ticks once for the entire simulation. Can anyone help me code this in a different way in order to have the ticks increase each time the turtles (collectively) move from patch to patch? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the portion of code where move is being called

```
  to find-shortest-path-to-destination
  place-turtles
  label-destination
  foreach sort ships
 [ ask ? 
  [ 
    set path find-a-path current-waypoint target-waypoint
    set optimal-path path
    set current-path path  
  ]
 ]
  move
end
```

Comment: @mattsap Move it called once after the paths have been determined. Reset-ticks only occurs at the beginning during setup.  I've added some more code to my question showing where move is called. Thanks for your help

Comment: Normally one puts `tick` at the end of a procedure, not the beginning — see http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#ticks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change your code to the following and put move inside of a repeat block. Essentially, everyone moves 1 path unit at a time and then move is called again,which then calls the next tick-event to occur

```
to move
     tick
     ask-concurrent ships with [length current-path != 0]
     [
        face first current-path
        move-to first current-path
        set current-path remove-item 0 current-path
        wait 0.08
     ]

end
to go
    while [any? ships with [length current-path != 0]] [move]
end
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but `ask-concurrent` should be pretty much avoided at all costs. It is only included in NetLogo for backwards compatibility. I would also recommend not using `wait`, but instead using the speed slider to control the speed of the model.

Comment: I agree. I'm unsure of the original context, so I left those in to maintain integrity. ask-concurrent and wait should really be taken out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to work. However to have the repeat block repeat the total number of times necessary to reach the destination I would code it as such `if length current-path != 0
 [
  repeat 1 [move] ]` however then the move is in turtle context. Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Comment: I've edited the solution; however, I think you should use a forever button and just call move, instead of writing the control logic yourself.